# python linked list leetcode problem 21 Merge Two Sorted Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I had a quick question about linked lists in python. In the solution code shown below when I'm trying to merge two sorted linked lists. I was confused about the condition of the if and elif statements that had been included. If l1 for example was not null and l2 had been null, I want to add the rest of the 3 elements from l1 into my new linked list, but the code shows l1 and tail not being updated, so wouldn't it just add one of the 3?

My other question was about returning head.next. Would returning that automatically return every node from head.next to null ptr? Thanks!

```
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1: ListNode, l2: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        head = ListNode()
        tail = head
        
        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val < l2.val:
                tail.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                tail.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            tail = tail.next
        
        if l1:
            tail.next = l1
            #why don't I update l1 and tail
        elif l2:
            tail.next = l2
            #why don't I update l2and and tail
        return head.next
        #does returning head.next return every single value from head.next to null?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are using a linked list, so if you point to a specific node and that node has more nodes in it's next, then you'll get them all.

**So what's wrong here?**

Well, actually nothing. You're returning the `head -> next`, so basically you're returning the whole linked list. If you iterate through the list like this:

```
merged_list = solution.mergeTwoLists(lst1, lst2)
while merged_list:
    print(str(merged_list.val), end = ' -> ')
    merged_list = merged_list.next
print(merged_list)
```

For example, if you have the following linked lists `lst1` and `lst2` defined as below:

```
lst1 = ListNode(1)
lst1.next = ListNode(6)
lst1.next.next = ListNode(3)    # So lst1 is basically 1 -> 6 -> 3 -> None

lst2 = ListNode(4)
lst2.next = ListNode(5)
lst2.next.next = ListNode(2)    # And lst2 is basically 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> None
```

Then you'll get in the final result:

```
1 -> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 6 -> 3 -> None
```

Which is exactly what you've applied in the code.

Comment: ah so with the if elif statement that i had, if lst1 isn't at none then it'll add the rest of the nodes into my new linked list

Comment: yes, please note that one of your lists will become blank, I mean `None`, eventually. So the last `if-elif` will add the rest to the list.